# Adding items to a List Of does not show in datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, list, xaml, datagrid

My DataGrid in xaml code:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=VoSamArtList}" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,10,5,5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

My Button to add items to the list in xaml:

```
<Button Grid.Row="2"  Click="Button_Click"/>
```

My Property in vb code:

```
Private _oVoSamArtLijst As New List(Of Product)
Public Property VoSamArtLijst As List(Of Product)
    Get
        Return _oVoSamArtLijst
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Product))
        _oVoSamArtLijst = value
        RaisePropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
```

And my Button Click in vb code:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    VoSamArtList.Add(New Product("Id", "Length", "Width", "Height", "Code", "Quality", "Description", "Price"))
End Sub
```

I have several other `Properties` in my project that update just as they have to like `Binding` test from `TextBoxes` to `Labels`. But binding this `List` to the `DataGrid` appears to be a difficult one. If I run the program, the columns are generated and have the correct name from the `Artikel Class`.

I'm probably forgetting something that has to be done with `Binding` `List Of`'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need to use an ObservableCollection

[ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms668604%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

An ObservableCollection notifies when items are added or removed.

This might not be perfect as I use C#

```
Private _oVoSamArtLijst As New ObservableCollection(Of Product)
Public Property VoSamArtLijst As ObservableCollection(Of Product)
    Get
        Return _oVoSamArtLijst
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of Product))
        _oVoSamArtLijst = value
        RaisePropertyChanged()
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: So I now have ` Public VoSamArtLijst As New ObservableCollection(Of Product)` and added `RaisePropertyChanged("VoSamArtLijst")` to my `Button_Click` event but nothing is happening.

Comment: Where do you have ` Public VoSamArtLijst As New ObservableCollection(Of Product)`?

Comment: It was me being a noob...I thought I only needed `Public VoSamArtLijst As New ObservableCollection(Of Product)`, but not. Added my property again like your example in C# (I know C# so no problem ;) ). Working like a charm now, tnx.

Comment: The UI only sees the public property.  You probably had an implicit cast of the private in the get going on.